# How to see the attributes of argparse.NameSpace Python object?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, argparse

For a project involving multiple scripts (data processing, model tuning, model training, testing, etc.) I may keep all my `<class 'argparse.ArgumentParser'>` objects as the return value of functions for each script task in a module I name `cli.py`. However, in the calling script itself (`__main__`), after calling `args = parser.parse_args()`, if I type `args.` in VS Code I get no suggested attributes that are specific to that object. **How can I get suggested attributes of `argparse.NameSpace` objects in VS Code?**

E.g.,

```py
"""Module for command line interface for different scripts."""
import argparse
def some_task_parser(description: str) -> argparse.ArgumentParser:
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description)
  parser.add_argument('some_arg')
  return parser
```

then

```py
"""Script for executing some task."""
from cli import some_task_parser
if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = some_task_parser('arbitrary task')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  print(args.)  # I WANT SUGGESTED ATTRIBUTES (SUCH AS args.some_arg) TO POP UP!!
```

Comment: Since your question appears to be specifically about the behaviour of your IDE, I have  added the corresponding tag.

Comment: The `args` namespace is a python object.  It is not a `method`, so doesn't have defined arguments.  It has attributes.

Comment: I have corrected my question to use the term attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about VSCode, in an `ipython` session, the tab complete does show the available attributes of `Namespace`.  `argparse.Namespace` is a relatively simple object class.  What you want, I think, are just the `attributes` of this object.

```
In [238]: args = argparse.Namespace(test='one', foo='three', bar=3)
In [239]: args
Out[239]: Namespace(bar=3, foo='three', test='one')
In [240]: args.
                bar      test    
                foo      args.txt
```

But those attributes will not be available during development.  They are put there by the parsing action, at run time. They cannot be reliably deduced from the `parser` setup.  Certainly `argparse` does not provide such a help.

I often recommend that developers include a

```
print(args)
```

during the debugging phase, so they get a clear idea of what the parser does.

Comment: This makes sense. I was hoping I would be able to see the attributes before executing during runtime, but it's not a big deal if I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Use `args.__dict__` to get the names and values. If you need just the argument names, then `[key for key in args.__dict__.keys()]` will give the list of them.